# Java bind Map size with ObjectProperty<Integer>

Tags: java, binding

I'm having a UI element which I need updated when a map is being updated. I want to bind the map size with the ObjectProperty, but the `.bind()` method does not allow it. How can I bind the property with the map size? Code example:

```
public class ContainerOJ {

    protected final ObjectProperty<Integer> objCount;
    protected Map<String, String> stackMap;

    public ContainerOJ() {
        this.objCount = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(0);
        this.stackMap = new HashMap<>();

//        objCount.bind(stackMap.size());
    }

    public void addToStack(String newObj) {
        if (stackMap.get(newObj) != null) {
            /* Obj:{}, already exists in the Stack:{} */
            return;
        }

        stackMap.put(newObj, newObj);
        objCount.set(stackMap.size());
    }

    public Integer getObjCount() {
        return objCount.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Integer> objCountProperty() {
        return objCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `ObjectProperty<Integer>`.  Use [ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.html) and [ReadOnlyIntegerProperty](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyIntegerProperty.html) instead:

```
protected final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper objCount;

public ContainerOJ() {
    this.objCount = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();
    this.stackMap = new HashMap<>();
}

//...

public int getObjCount() {
    return objCount.get();
}

public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty objCountProperty() {
    return objCount.getReadOnlyProperty();
}
```

You can actually make this easier by using an [ObservableMap](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ObservableMap.html):

```
protected final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper objCount;
protected final ObservableMap<String, String> stackMap;

public ContainerOJ() {
    this.objCount = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();
    this.stackMap = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

    objCount.bind(Bindings.size(stackMap));
}

public void addToStack(String newObj) {
    stackMap.putIfAbsent(newObj, newObj);
}

public int getObjCount() {
    return objCount.get();
}

public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty objCountProperty() {
    return objCount.getReadOnlyProperty();
}
```

I’m not sure why you’re using a Map here, since your keys and values are identical.  It looks like you should be using a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html).  More specifically, an ObservableSet:

```
protected final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper objCount;
protected final ObservableSet<String> stackMap;

public ContainerOJ() {
    this.objCount = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();
    this.stackMap = FXCollections.observableSet();

    objCount.bind(Bindings.size(stackMap));
}

public void addToStack(String newObj) {
    stackMap.add(newObj);
}

public int getObjCount() {
    return objCount.get();
}

public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty objCountProperty() {
    return objCount.getReadOnlyProperty();
}
```

Comment: Using key and value the same as per minimum reproducible example, as in my project I have a map of objects, and the class has more stuff as well, which is not relevat to this case. @VGR I can see the usages of ObservableMap! didn't thought of using FX for this -- much appreciated